# How to reference javascript json

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

I can reference this data fine:

1. `$("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource.options.batch` (console shows `false`)

But I can't seem to reference this data:

2. `$("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource._pristineData[0].DepartmentCode`
   [image]

It says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DepartmentCode' of undefined`

3. So I tried this:
   `$("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource._pristineData`
   and it just shows this:

[image]

How can I get `080` DepartmentCode?

4. I tried this `$("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource._online` and got `true`

Thanks!

Comment: Best guess is array hasn't been populated at the time you are looking for it

Comment: @h2ooooooo `_pristineData` isn't within `.options`. @charlietfl looks like it, it's strange when I do `.dataSource` I can see the data, but not when I go deeper.

Comment: based on your screenshot you should use `$("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource._pristineData[0][0].DepartmentCode` since `_pristineData` is a 2 dimensional array

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I tried that too, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` Reference: `$("#treelist").data('kendoTreeList').dataSource._pristineData[0][0].DepartmentCode`

Comment: If `_pristineData[0]` is undefined, `_pristineData[0][0]` will certainly also suffer the same problem.  In this case, it's not a 2-dimensional array: there are so many items in the array that the debugger is helpfully breaking the items of the array into groups of 100.

Comment: The leading underscore suggests `_pristineData` is meant to be private.  Why are you trying to access `_pristineData`?  What is the end goal?

Comment: @Amy I need the data to show on the user UI the `DepartmentCode`, and this is an easy way to get it. I've just added a 4th example where I can access `_online` just fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `dataSource.data()` to get the data?

Comment: @Amy I've just tried that and got this: https://i.imgur.com/MciF3R3.png (looks like there's no data)

Comment: Please include a more complete code sample of that attempt.  If `dataSource.data()` returns nothing, you're running that line before the datasource *has* the data.  I get the impression your question is heavily dependent on *when* you're trying to get at any of this.  Please give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to get the value by invoking `DataBound`:
`events.DataBound("dataBound");`

```
function dataBound(e) {
console.log(e.sender.tbody[0].firstElementChild.cells[1].innerText);
}
```

It's not pretty but it works.